# AWS Lambda C# - invoking lambda through its vpc endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

is it possible to invoke a lambda from another lambda through its vpc endpoint  (not through  its name)?
I can't invoke the lambda directly because the calling lambda is in a VPC and the lambda i want to call is not in the VPC.

It seems the AWS-SDK in the caller lambda needs an internet access to invoke another lambda(default behaviour) and in the VPC i don't have one (i can't add a NAT Gateway or a Nat Instance).

if the lambdas are in the same vpc i would use this code:

```
AmazonLambdaConfig lambdaConfig = new AmazonLambdaConfig() {  RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1 };    
AmazonLambdaClient lCli = new AmazonLambdaClient("****APIKEY******", "****SECRET******", lambdaConfig);   //se presente la variabile di ambiente AWS_PROFILE prende si logga con quelle credenziali
Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest lambdaRequest = new Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest()
{
     FunctionName = "notification-prd-notifyses",
     InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse,
     Payload =  myJobj.ToString()
};

Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeResponse response = lCli.InvokeAsync(lambdaRequest).Result;
```

so, the question is: **can i invoke a lambda referring to its VPC endpoint i created (henche through its DNS name)?**

i can't use/create an apigateway as well, or associate a vpc endpoint to it, so the question is related only to the direct invocation lambda to lambda. is it possible?

Comment: The same could should work when your first function is in VPC, and the second is not. Have you tried?

Comment: yes, i tried but without success, i suppose i can't call any lambda at all if my calling lambda is in a VPC without an internet connection (lambdas outside vpcs are always permetted to connect to internet, lambdas inside vpcs not

Comment: You don't have VPC interface endpoint for lambda? From your post, it seems that you have one? Maybe its misconfigured?

Comment: @Marcin correct! i've one but i don't know how to call it with that interface instead of lambda's name: I mean, i don't know how to modify the code written in my post above to referr to  the VPC interface's dns

Comment: Do you have `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` for vpc and `private dns` for the endpoint enabled?

Comment: @Marcin about enableDnsHostnames(enabled) and enableDnsSupport for the vpc (i suppose enabled, but i'm not sure, look at the picture please) 
[![1.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/C5KV00Ns/1.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/CB92CW9R).

About "private dns for the endpoint" no, i haven't enabled it so i have availabe only the defalut (regional and zonal) dns created automatically when i've created the vpc endpoint
[![2.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/NfmLP7KG/2.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/bsYzZn04)

Comment: If possible, you should try with enabled private dns names option. This should allow you to simply re-use the existing code without any modifications.

Comment: Ok i'll try as soon as possible.
"without modification" you mean don't change this line of code? `Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest() { FunctionName = "notification-prd-notifyses",...`.

"notification-prd-notifyses" is the name of the lambda! can i leave it as is? or i sholud use the dns? thanks so much for your precious help!

Comment: the purpose of private dns is that it should work seamlessly. You shouldn't need to change any dns endpoints in your code to use the vpc interface endpoint.

Comment: you are great! do you know if to enable the private DNS for the vpc interface has extra cost?

Comment: There is no extra price for private dns. For VPC endpoints you pay per hour and per GB as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/).